# Linux - opened port, but still fail to connect to it using telnet

Tags: firewall, port, telnet, firewalld

I'm currently working on CentOS 7.3.

In order to activate SNMP, I installed it, configured it and successfully started the service using the `firewall-cmd` command.

Now, I realized that I need to open the port 161 to make the SNMP start communicating. therefore I ran the following commands below.

`$sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=161/udp --zone-public`
`Success`
`$sudo firewall-cmd --reload`
`Success`

After that I checked if the new options are successfully added, and everything turned out to be fine.

But, while trying to check if I had no problem connecting to the port 161 using telnet, I got the following error message.

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: No route to host
```

Is there any part I'm missing in this step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot telnet snmp port because its not TCP, is UDP;

Try to test it  with snmpget command from the net-snmp package :

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmpget.html

Answer (score 0):

To provide more understanding please find this post from @tkedwards on [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/telneting-to-a-udp-port-353876/) to understand the result of using telnet to check connectivity on UDP port :

> "UDP is a connectionless protocol which means it basically just sends
>   packets out to the specified destination. TCP is connection-oriented
>   which means it establishes a connection to the other end using the
>   '3-way handshake'.
>
> So it makes sense to apply the 'telnet' paradigm to TCP - you make
>   connection to a specific host and port, you still remain connected
>   (for a period of time) even if you aren't sending any data and you can
>   send and receive data continuously without having to reconnect in
>   between.
>
> UDP on the other hand doesn't really fit the telnet model - its more
>   of a fire-and-forget system where you fire-off a series of packets
>   towards the destination. You then go on with something else (or just
>   wait doing nothing) until (or if) the remote process sends some
>   packets back."

So in resume UDP its not something you can really check unless it will give you information back.